# How do I hide path in my vs code terminal when I execute my c++ programs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, terminal

Whenever I execute c++ programs in visual studio code, I see an unnecessary path in the terminal. Is there a way to hide it? I only want output in the terminal.

here's how it looks:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.450]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Manisha\Desktop\c c++>cd "c:\Users\Manisha\Desktop\cpp\" && g++ character.cpp -o character && "c:\Users\Manisha\Desktop\cpp\"character       
Enter a character: A

The character is a capital letter     
c:\Users\Manisha\Desktop\cpp>
```

Comment: The only way to do that would be to have your program create it's own terminal. Not a straightforward task for a beginner.

Comment: BTW I can count four different paths in your post. Which ones are you complaining about, all of them?

Comment: You want to see just the line `Enter a character: A`, followed by a blank line, followed by `The character is a capital letter`?